# How can I dentify and delete superceded duplicity back up files?

Tags: backup, filemanager, duplicity

I have numerous duplicity files in my Google Drive that appear to be chewing up storage, however each file is quite small. There are several variations of these files; duplicity-inc(remental?) duplicity-new-signatures, duplicity-full and possibly others. I understand that these are associated with back ups, but don't understand how this works.

Given that some of these files are quite old I presume that some of the older ones would have been superceded and are no longer needed.

How can I identify and delete files that are no longer needed?

Or have I misunderstood how this works?

Comment: Have you read `man duplicity` on this topic? One easy way is two commands: Run a full backup, then delete everything older than that full backup. If you have not run a full backup in a very long time, that may be the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the duplicity manual.
My problem is that I'm very new to this - first time.  My backups are fully automated, I must have set something up somehow when I started using Ubuntu.
It appears to me that I need to know some stuff before I can do anything, e.g. I need to know the path, permissions, directories etc that duplicity uses to backup to my Google Drive. 
How can I get duplicity to show me this info?

Comment: Re-discover the shell script(s) or cron job(s) or systemd timer(s) that you created to fully-automate your backups. Duplicity won't regurgitate where you left those instructions; you must search your memory and your notes. Additional point: A backup is worthless unless you can successfully restore from that backup on a bad day. Ensure your notes are clear about how to do so.

Comment: I launched show applications and typed deja in the search bar and found Backups which showed that it was keeping backups for ever, I reset this to 6 months. Will this automatically delete all older backups next time around or do I have to manually flush these?

Comment: I suggest revising your question to ask the updated question that you want answered.